# Raspberry pi 3 does't work with internet

Tags: internet, chromium, web-browsers

I have a raspberry pi model 3 B using Raspbian. When ever I go on an internet browser, it is a few seconds before it crashes. I have tried
Epiphany, Chromium and NetSurf. It has no errors, it just crashes. Also, it hovers at 25% CPU usage before crashing, and the pi stays turned on. Just the web browser crashes.

Comment: Which browser? Which OS? What if anything is in the log files?

Comment: Epiphany and netsurf and chromium. On raspian

Comment: How are you powering the Pi? How is the Pi connected to the network? can you ping 8.8.8.8 and ping google.com? Have you tried a second SD card with a fresh install of Raspbian?

Comment: I'm powering pi by outlet USA/CAN and I'm using wifi. I haven't tried ping. How do I use ping?

Comment: to ping open a command prompt and enter ping 8.8.8.8 and ping google.com? What is between the electrical outlet and the Pi. Have you tried using Ethernet instead of WiFi?

Comment: I don't have easy access to my router and there is also a power bar, but there is an adapter.

Comment: I can ping, but it won't stop.

Comment: Ctrl c to stop the ping command

Comment: Have you tested the voltage on the Pi? Does the lightning bolt appear in the upper right corner or a rainbow square? If you are using a Pi 2 or 3, does the red LED flash or is it on steady?

Comment: I have a problem, the ping command  won't stop running!

Comment: And the led is steady.

Comment: @UbuntuUser you need to tell us what it says on the back of that Power adapter! Please type here all the information on it. The text maybe extremely small and hard to read or on a label.  The important information my look like **5v**, **12v**, **1000mha**, **1.5A**, **2.5A**, **2500mha**

Comment: I looked and it is blank

Comment: Also the CTRL+C command didn't work. It went on and on until I lost power to my house.

Comment: I found some stuff on the power adapter.  `Input 100-240v AC` `Input 50-60 Hz/0.5A `  `Output 5v DC/2.5 A`